# How can I add waitbar in the current GUI window MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am having a GUI figure, which contains some buttons, I want to show waitbar on the same GUI window on which buttons are placed, I tried different solutions but in vain. e.g when user clicks on button it starts showing me waitbar on left bottom side of the figure.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried already? Because it seems easier to just make a custom waitbar function out of a rectangle and some text in your GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a java waitbar in your figure.

Put this in the OpeningFcn

```
PB=javaObjectEDT(javax.swing.JProgressBar);
javacomponent(PB,[10,10,200,20],gcf); %put at bottom part of the current figure
set(handles.output.Children(1),'Tag','first_bar'); %make sure you can find it back
```

In the callback of any function you can then set the bar to a value between 0 and 100 using this code:

```
h=findobj(handles.output.Children,'Tag','first_bar');
set(h.JavaPeer,'Value',rand(1)*100)
```

You can make it visible or invisible just as you would any GUI object in Matlab using

```
h=findobj(handles.output.Children,'Tag','first_bar');
set(h,'visible','off');
```

Here you can find details about the [JProgressBar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) . For example using this you get a string with the progress inside the bar.

```
h=findobj(handles.output.Children,'Tag','first_bar');
set(h.JavaPeer,'StringPainted',1)
```

Comment: Thanks alot this code is perfectly what i need, but
handles.output.Children(1).Visible='off'; does n't make progressbar invisible

Comment: Maybe you have a different version of matlab. I put an alternate code using `set`.

Comment: I am using MATLAB 2017.

Comment: Does the new answer work for you? I tested it on 2016b

Comment: Yes it works for me. Can I make this progressbar like h=findobj(handles.output.Children,'Tag','first_bar');
set(h,'Indeterminate',1,'SrtringPainted',0); and vice versa?
I have just only added one progressbar, I have two buttons each other can be altered from Inderminate state to determinate state.

Comment: Yes, should work. You can add more but remember to give them different tags.